# How to create pivot table using vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am newbie in vba and am trying to create a `PivotTable` using VBA with excel.

I would like to creat like as below image as input sheet.

[image: Image of data]

I am trying to add row labels of `region`, `month`, `number`, `status` and values are `value1`, `value2` and `total` here I am able to set range for pivot, while executing it creates "pivottable" sheet only. not generate any pivot table for sheet1.

**My Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Input_File__1()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).TextBox1.Text = Application.GetOpenFilename()

End Sub

'======================================================================

Public Sub Output_File_1()

Dim get_fldr, item As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo nextcode:

    item = .SelectedItems(1)
    If Right(item, 1) <> "\" Then
        item = item & "\"
    End If
End With

nextcode:
get_fldr = item
Set fldr = Nothing
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).TextBox2.Text = get_fldr

End Sub

'======================================================================

Public Sub Process_start()

Dim Raw_Data_1, Output As String
Dim Raw_data, Start_Time As String
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Start_Time = Time()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Raw_Data_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).TextBox1.Text
Output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).TextBox2.Text

Workbooks.Open Raw_Data_1: Set Raw_data = ActiveWorkbook
Raw_data.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

On Error Resume Next

'Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Sheets.Add before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivottable"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivottable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).coloumn
Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create_(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

With PTable.PivotFields("Region")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: What errors are you getting and where? There is at least one spelling mistake here     LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).coloumn     <= column

Comment: Comment out the on error resume next to and step through the code with F8 to see where problems may be. Make it clear in the question what isn't working the way you would like and what you have tried. Is there some code missing?

Comment: pivot not create for first row as region

Comment: did you try creating the pivot manually and  using the macro recorder? It will give you the approximate syntax. Also, correct the spelling mistake.

Comment: Yes i already created it, which is working fine. but i am trying to get it to work in dynamically for any input

Comment: i am not seeing any error, but no output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159808/discussion-between-suresh-and-qharr).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159811/discussion-between-love-mam-and-qharr).

Answer (score 7):

This needs some tidying up but should get you started.

Note the use of Option Explicit so variables have to be declared.

Columns names are as per your supplied workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

     Dim PSheet As Worksheet
     Dim DSheet As Worksheet
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim LastCol As Long
     Dim PRange As Range
     Dim PCache As PivotCache
     Dim PTable As PivotTable

     Sheets.Add
     ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivottable"

    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivottable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

    With PTable.PivotFields("Region")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With PTable.PivotFields("Channel")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With PTable.PivotFields("AW code")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With

    PTable.AddDataField PSheet.PivotTables _
        ("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("Bk"), "Sum of Bk", xlSum
    PTable.AddDataField PSheet.PivotTables _
        ("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("DY"), "Sum of DY", xlSum
    PTable.AddDataField PSheet.PivotTables _
        ("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("TOTal"), "Sum of TOTal", xlSum

End Sub
```

Comment: also nice, just modufy the names of the `PivotFields` to match with this post :)

Answer (score 1):

The code in my answer below is a little long, but it should deliver you the result you are seeking for.

First, to be on the safe side, first check if `"Pivottable"` sheet already exists in `Raw_data` workbook object (no need to create it again).

Second, the code is divided in the middle to 2 sections:

1. If the MACRO was ran before (this is the 2+ times you are running it), then `"PRIMEPivotTable"` Pivot-Table is already created, and there’s no need to create it again, or to set-up the Pivot-Table’s fields.
   All you need to do is refresh the `PivotTable` with the updated `PivotCache` (with updated Pivot-Cache’s source range).
2. If this is the first time running this MACRO, then you need to set-up the `PivotTable` and all necessary `PivotFields`.

Detaile explanation of every step inide the code's comments.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoPivot()

Dim Raw_data As Workbook
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim Raw_Data_1 As String, Output As String, Start_Time As String

Start_Time = Time()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Raw_Data_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).TextBox1.Text
Output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).TextBox2.Text

' set the WorkBook object
Set Raw_data = Workbooks.Open(Raw_Data_1)

Set DSheet = Raw_data.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' first check if "Pivottable" sheet exits (from previous MACRO runs)
On Error Resume Next
Set PSheet = Raw_data.Sheets("Pivottable")
On Error GoTo 0

If PSheet Is Nothing Then '
    Set PSheet = Raw_data.Sheets.Add(before:=Raw_data.ActiveSheet) ' create a new worksheet and assign the worksheet object
    PSheet.Name = "Pivottable"
Else ' "Pivottable" already exists
    ' do nothing , or something else you might want

End If

With DSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' set the Pivot-Cache Source Range with the values found for LastRow and LastCol
    Set PRange = .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

' set a new/updated Pivot Cache object
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal))

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable") ' check if "PRIMEPivotTable" Pivot-Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PTable Is Nothing Then ' Pivot-Table still doesn't exist, need to create it
    ' create a new Pivot-Table in "Pivottable" sheet
    Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("A1"), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

    With PTable
        ' add the row fields
        With .PivotFields("Region")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("month")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        With .PivotFields("number")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Status")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 4
        End With

        ' add the 3 value fields (as Sum of..)
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("value1"), "Sum of value1", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("value2"), "Sum of value2", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("TOTal"), "Sum of TOTal", xlSum
    End With

Else ' Pivot-Table "PRIMEPivotTable" already exists >> just update the Pivot-Table with updated Pivot-Cache (update Source Range)

     ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PTable.ChangePivotCache PCache
    PTable.RefreshTable
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And that is a nice and tidy version! +1

Comment: @QHarr LOL, thanks :) too much free time on Sunday (and perhaps too many answers here on the exact same matter, maybe only 95% similar)

Comment: True. But i haven't got much quicker at finding them (existing answers) again. I had seen a nicely tidied up version of this very recently, was it you? I did note one person who actually included their most commonly referred to posts and materials, in their about me section ,which seemed quite sensible.

Comment: @QHarr  could be me, I don't remember , there are weeks which I can't remember what posts I've read, or even answered myself (and I go again to check them out). I don't have anything interesting like that in "about me" section, unfortunately