# how to match unique data from one column to another column which has same data but multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA coding, I am struggling with a problem, need help with coding. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FutER.jpg]

**Question is: Image Links is above** and described below

There are two columns, column A and B on Sheet1. Column A has 500 rows with the different person name but the same name is repeated serval times. column B has task status( i.e completed, open, closed) against each person name.

**The task is to create a new worksheet which is kind of report of the sheet1** It has unique names from that 500 rows and checks how many tasks is completed or delayed or opened.

This my code to remove duplicated and create unique.

```
Sub CreateUniqueList()      
    Dim lastrow As Long          
    Dim ws As String   
    ws = "Sheet1"      
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row      
    Sheets.Add.Name = "mysheet"        
    Sheets(ws).Range("A1:A" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _     
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _         
        CopyToRange:=Sheets("mysheet").Range("B1"), _  
        UNIQUE:=True  
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use a Pivot table for this

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank for your prompt reply. Tim, will the Pivot table will get updated automatically when the more data is added in source data in future? Thanks again!!!

Comment: As long as the pivot table is from a table and not just a cell range.  You can google create a table in excel to see how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

@AdityaPal You can create a Pivot Table. To update it, after changing the source data, you can right'click the pivot table and click Refresh.

If you want to have a macro setup to automatically create a pivot table for you - then there a couple of StackOverFlow threads about this (i.e. [How to create pivot table using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487657/how-to-create-pivot-table-using-vba?rq=1)